# Time complexity of contains(Object o), in an ArrayList of Objects

Tags: java, arraylist, time-complexity

As the title says, I was wondering what the time complexity of the [`contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method of an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
O(n)
```

> The `size`, `isEmpty`, `get`, `set`, `iterator`, and `listIterator` operations run in constant time. The `add` operation runs in amortized *constant time*, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 14):

it's O(n) for [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you look into the source code for `ArrayList` and check its `contains` method it looks as below:

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return indexOf(o) >= 0;
}
```

`contains` delegates the check to the `indexOf` method. So, if we check the `indexOf` implementation it is as follows:

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

As it can be seen from the code, in order to find an index of a given element, one, in the worst case, must iterate through the whole array. As a size of the array grows and so does the search time by an element. Hence, the time complexity of `contains` method is `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of elements in the list.

Answer (score 1):

its `O(n)`. `contains(Object o)` is implemented on `indexOf()` which takes `O(n)`. So complexity of `contains(Object o)` is defensively `O(n)`

Here are some other if you need:

```
add() - O(1)
add(index, element) – O(n)
get() – O(1)
set() – O(1)
remove() –  (n)
indexOf()` – O(n)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  two small comments: 1) I am not sure you need to specify "defensively", that is already implied by using `O` notation; 2) technically `add` is not really `O(1)`, in the worst case it is linear, but it runs in *amortized* constant time (see the answer by @davin).