# What DS to use for search a string in set of strings in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a few strings(about 100) and I want to store them in a Data Structure and then later I want to search it for a particular string to check whether its present or not. What DS in Java will be best in this case for fast searching.

The actual use case is that I want to create a catalog for books and need to find out whether a particular title is present or not.

All the strings are unique. I dont want to implement any DS myself but want to use any of the Collections already present in Java.

Comment: Any dictionary data structure would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you use any **List** to store all the strings and use **contains()** method to find whether it present in your **List** or not.

You can even use **Set** but in that case your strings must be unique.

Comment: In case of a list and millions of book titles O(n) would be searching time hence tree or hash tables are suitable.

Comment: @Yavar He has mentioned that list is about 100 length. Thats why I suggested about List.

Comment: What is the time complexity for search in case of List?

Comment: @Neerav its O(n) in worst case, as it will check each element and compare. you can also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771740/time-complexity-of-containsobject-o-in-an-arraylist-of-objects

Comment: vs O(1) for lookups in a `HashSet`, for example.

Comment: @milkplusvellocet yes of course. Thats the only reason +1 by me for kgiannakakis

Answer (score 3):

The obvious choice would be to use an implementation of the [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface. This exposes a convenient [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method, which you can use to test if a specific title exists. You could also use an implementation of a Map, like [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to associate a String with an object. This will allow you to store information about your book and easily access it.

The advantage of using a Set or a Map, is that searching for a specific key is very effective. You can't have duplicate items in a Set.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) implementation. The `contains` method will tell you if a particular `String` title is present or not