# Loop over List for finding particular Value

Tags: java, string, list, loops

I have a list huge list of strings. The strings are either "ACCEPTED", "OK" or " NOT OK".

If list contains one `ACCEPTED` the final value should be `ACCEPTED`, irregardless of the other values. If there is no `ACCEPTED` but there is an `OK`, the final value should be `OK`. If neither of them appear, the final value should be `NOT OK`.

I can use `String.contains()` method to check the values contains certain string, but I have a huge list. Therefore I am afraid it will cause the performance issue.

```
if(s.contains(("ACCEPTED"))) {
               value= "ACCEPTED";
               break;
            } else if(s.contains(("OK"))) {
                value= "OK";
                break;
            } else {
                value= "NOT OK";
            }
```

Will this method work for huge lists, or do I need to use something else?

Comment: And why do you have a list and not a set?

Comment: My service returning List only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a question if `ArrayList.contains()` is quick enough. This has already been answered on SO here:

- [Time complexity of contains(Object o), in an ArrayList of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5771740/633093)

Time complexity of `ArrayList.contains()` is `O(n)`. In layman's terms, performance scales linearly. A list with twice as many items will take twice the time to execute. This is almost as good as it gets and IMO you should not be worried about performance.

But as tom said, it's better to use a `Set` which by definition does not store duplicate values.

EDIT:

Here is an example of working code, you can also test it [here](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/CBWMMMNTZO):

```
import java.util.*;

class myCode
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        ArrayList<String> testList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        String s1 = new String ("ACCEPTED");
        String s2 = new String ("OK");
        String s3 = new String ("NOT OK");


        testList.add(s1);
        testList.add(s2);
        testList.add(s3);


        String status= "";

        if(testList.contains("ACCEPTED")) {
             status= "ACCEPTED";
        }
        else if(testList.contains("OK")) {
            status= "OK";
        } 
          else {
            status= "NOT OK";
         }
        System.out.println(status);

    }
}
```

Comment: But always it returns NOT OK, As per my requirement, it should return ACCEPTED if any one of the Status values is ACCEPTED.  Here is my code:                Status s1 = new Status ("ACCEPTED");
        Status s2 = new Status ("OK");
        Status s3 = new Status ("NOT OK");


        testList.add(s1);
        testList.add(s2);
        testList.add(s3);


        String status= "";

        if(testList.contains("ACCEPTED")) {
            status= "ACCEPTED";

        } else if(testList.contains("OK")) {
         status= "OK";
      } else {
    status= "NOT OK";
     }